# Почему возникает ошибка format string is not a string literal?

Tags: c, printf

Согласно стандарту функция `printf` имеет прототип: 
`int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);`

Собственно, сабж:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    const char *format = "hello world!";
    printf(format);

    return 0;
}
```

Протест `Clang`:

```
printf.c:7:12: error: format string is not a string literal
      (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
    printf(format);
           ^~~~~~
printf.c:7:12: note: treat the string as an argument to avoid this
    printf(format);
           ^
           "%s", 
1 error generated
```

Почему возникает такая ошибка? Ведь строка форматирования соответствует прототипу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Собственно, clang ругается на совсем другое. Первой ошибкой он говорит, что хорошо бы строку форматирования явно задать литералом, а не переменной, так как переменную может кто то случайно поменять или подменить. А явное - это всегда лучше. Подобная строка форматирования сколько раз была причиной багов и уязвимостей, что clang решает предупредить.

Второй строкой он говорит, что красивее эту конструкцию писать так

```
printf("%s", format);
```

Но иногда лучше сразу писать

```
puts(format);
```

Но на самом деле ошибка возникает из за `-Werror`, который заставляет warning трактовать как ошибки.